# Comma Separate Jekyll Posts

Tags: loops, jekyll

I want to list all my posts within `site.categories.projects` as a comma separated sentence. There's documentation for displaying `{{ site.tags }}` as `array_to_sentence_string` but how can I use the filter with a `for` loop?

Comment: Dear Stackexchange, please provide some feedback as to WHY these questions get downvotes. I seriously cannot improve my questions, or answers for that matter, if there is no explanation on why this question is "bad".

Answer (score 1):

```
# empty array 
{% assign postsTitlesArray = '' | split:':' %}

# pushing categorie posts title in our array
{% for post in site.categories.one %}
  {% assign postsTitlesArray = postsTitlesArray | push: post.title %}
{% endfor %}

{{ postsTitlesArray | array_to_sentence_string }}
```